# How to assign firedate to datepicker

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, datepicker, nsexception

I am trying to create an app. I need to send a notification daily at a time the user decides I have used a date picker for the user to decide when they get the notification. I am also found a way to get it repeat but now I am having trouble assigning the date picker to the fire date. Please answer in swift.
code:

```
import UIKit

class TechByteSchedulingViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

   @IBAction func SavePressed(sender: UIButton) {
       func sendNotification(sender: UIButton) {
           var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
           localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
           localNotification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
           localNotification.alertBody = "check out your daily byte"
           localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
           localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
           localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

           UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

}
```

Here is the code from the app delegate 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate is highlighted when I press done after setting the date picker

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))) {

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: nil))
    var notification = UILocalNotification()
            // play default sound
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
```

return true
    }

Here is the errors in the console
2015-07-27 15:04:20.723 Daily Byte[3058:170905] Could not load the "second" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "NikhilKanamarlaDaily-Byte"
2015-07-27 15:04:20.723 Daily Byte[3058:170905] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
2015-07-27 15:04:20.723 Daily Byte[3058:170905] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
2015-07-27 15:04:20.724 Daily Byte[3058:170905] Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "NikhilKanamarlaDaily-Byte"
2015-07-27 15:04:20.729 Daily Byte[3058:170905] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
2015-07-27 15:04:20.729 Daily Byte[3058:170905] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
2015-07-27 15:04:20.729 Daily Byte[3058:170905] Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "NikhilKanamarlaDaily-Byte"
2015-07-27 15:04:20.729 Daily Byte[3058:170905] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
2015-07-27 15:04:20.729 Daily Byte[3058:170905] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
2015-07-27 15:04:20.729 Daily Byte[3058:170905] Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "NikhilKanamarlaDaily-Byte"
2015-07-27 15:04:27.565 Daily Byte[3058:170905] -[Daily_Byte.TechByteSchedulingViewController DateChosen:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd2a4bbef0
2015-07-27 15:04:27.589 Daily Byte[3058:170905] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Daily_Byte.TechByteSchedulingViewController DateChosen:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd2a4bbef0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100ba7c65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102712bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100baf0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b0513c ___forwarding_** + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b04cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000101447d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010155950a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001015588d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000101494958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000101495282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010145b541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000101468cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010144359c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100adb431 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100ad12fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100ad0934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100ad0366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104b7ba3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001014468c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    19  Daily Byte                          0x000000010098cbf7 main + 135
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102e48145 start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Can you give some information on what you're seeing that isn't working? Is it firing at the wrong time/not at all?

Comment: When I hit the done button in my app it crashes and [class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate] is highlighted

Comment: Can you provide the relevant lines from the console? The answer will be in there somewhere.

Comment: @Braains Done the errors in the console are in my description

Comment: It looks to me like you have the "Done" button set in Interface Builder to trigger a selector called "DateChosen". If this is true then all you need to do is add that selector to your class. You can check this by going to your storyboard or nib file and selecting the done button and going to the outlets section of the inspector.

Comment: @Braains it worked but now the notifications aren't working

Comment: Were the notifications working before?